# Exibir diferentes mensagens em um site com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5

Boa tarde. Estou aprendendo JavaScript e iniciei um projeto para calcular o IMC de uma pessoa. Pesquisei como se faz a soma de dois números usando inputs no HTML e com base no código usado para a soma, converti ele para fazer a equação que calcula o IMC de uma pessoa.

O resultado saiu esse aqui => https://danisanttos.github.io/exercicio-IMC/ (Funciona bem apenas em desktop, ainda não aprendi muito sobre responsividade no CSS).

Porém, queria dar uma incrementada, por exemplo, se o resultado for um IMC abaixo ou acima da média, exiba após clicar no "Resultado" o resultado do calculo e um aviso dizendo que IMC ta acima ou abaixo. Seria bom também, exibir o "seu IMC é:" após clicar no resultado. Mas não faço ideia de como fazer e tentei pesquisar mas não sei os termos corretos para isso.

Se puderem me dar um help mas sem me crucificar eu vou agradecer muito <3
Esse é o html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <title>Calculador de IMC</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="js/javascript.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="content"> 
            <h1>CALCULADOR DE IMC</h1>

            <p></p><label>Digite o seu peso:</label>
            <input class="peso" type="number" min="1" max="999"><br>
                
            <p>Agora sua altura:</p>
                
            <label>M:</label>
            <input class="m" type="number" min="0" max="2">
                
            <label>CM:</label>                
            <input class="cm" type="number"  min="0" max="99">
                
            <button onclick="clicar()">RESULTADO</button>

            <p>Seu IMC é:</p>

            <p class="resultado"></p>
        
        </div> 

    </body>
</html>
```

Esse o JavaScript:

```
function clicar() {
    var peso = document.querySelector(".peso").value;
    var m = document.querySelector(".m").value;
    var cm = document.querySelector(".cm").value;
    var alt = m + "." + cm;
    var res = parseFloat(peso) / (parseFloat(alt) * parseFloat(alt));
    var imc = parseFloat(res.toFixed(2))
    document.querySelector(".resultado").innerHTML = imc;
}
```

Esse o CSS (Não sei se é necessário):

```
body {
    background-color: #8470FF;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 1;
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

.content {
    background-color: #aeb79b;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right:5%;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    left: 50%;
    
    transform: translatex(-50%);
}
```

Lembrando pessoal, estou aprendendo então o código não ta 100%. Uso essa página pra dar uma treinada.

valeeeeeeu :D

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar a condicional `switch` que avalia uma expressão, combinando o valor da expressão para um cláusula case, e executa as instruções  associadas ao case.

```js
function clicar() {
  var peso = document.querySelector(".peso").value;
  var m = document.querySelector(".m").value;
  var cm = document.querySelector(".cm").value;
  var alt = m + "." + cm;
  var res = parseFloat(peso) / (parseFloat(alt) * parseFloat(alt));
  var imc = parseFloat(res.toFixed(2));
  var classificacao = "";

switch (true) {
    case (imc < 18.5):
        classificacao =("Abaixo do peso");
        break;
    case (imc < 24.5):
        classificacao =("Peso normal");
        break;
    case (imc < 29.9):
        classificacao =("Sobrepeso");
        break;
    case (imc < 34.9):
        classificacao =("Obesidade grau 1");
        break;
    case (imc < 39.9):
        classificacao =("Obesidade grau 2");
        break;
    case (imc >= 39.9):
        classificacao =("Obesidade grau 3");
        break;
    default:
        classificacao =("");
        break;
}

  document.querySelector(".resultado").innerHTML = imc;
  document.querySelector(".classificacao").innerHTML = classificacao;
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #8470FF;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 1;
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

.content {
    background-color: #aeb79b;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right:5%;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    left: 50%;
    
    transform: translatex(-50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <title>Calculador de IMC</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="js/javascript.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="content"> 
            <h1>CALCULADOR DE IMC</h1>

            <p></p><label>Digite o seu peso:</label>
            <input class="peso" type="number" min="1" max="999"><br>
                
            <p>Agora sua altura:</p>
                
            <label>M:</label>
            <input class="m" type="number" min="0" max="2">    
            <label>CM:</label>                
            <input class="cm" type="number"  min="0" max="99">
                
            <button onclick="clicar()">RESULTADO</button>

            <p>Seu IMC é:</p>

            <p class="resultado"></p>
            <p class="classificacao"></p>
        
        </div> 

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fala ai, brother.
Esse código é só pra te dar uma luz. Acho que se baseando nele, você consegue o que deseja. Adapte para o seu código.

Se quiseres, de forma opcional, podes adicionar uma tabela para exibir as informações dos resultados para os usuários terem noções de cada índice. Abração

```js
function clicar() {
  var peso = document.querySelector(".peso").value;
  var m = document.querySelector(".m").value;
  var cm = document.querySelector(".cm").value;

  //Para o caso de algum do campos virem vazios. Essa condição evita retornar "NaN" no campo;
  if (peso == "" || m == "" || cm == "") {
    alert("Todos os campos devem ser preenchidos");
    document.querySelector(".resultado").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  }

  var alt = m + "." + cm;
  var res = parseFloat(peso) / (parseFloat(alt) * parseFloat(alt));
  var imc = parseFloat(res.toFixed(2))
  var classificacao = "";

  if (imc < 16) {
    classificacao = "Magreza grave";
  } else if (imc >= 16 && imc <= 17) {
    classificacao = "Magreza Moderada";
  } else if (imc > 17 && imc <= 18.5) {
    classificacao = "Magreza Leve";
  } else if (imc > 18.5 && imc <= 25) {
    classificacao = "Saudável";
  } else if (imc > 25 && imc <= 30) {
    classificacao = "Sobrepeso";
  } else if (imc > 30 && imc <= 35) {
    classificacao = "Obesidade Grau I";
  } else if (imc > 35 && imc <= 40) {
    classificacao = "Obesidade Grau II";
  } else if (imc > 40) {
    classificacao = "Obesidade Grau III";
  }

  document.querySelector(".resultado").innerHTML = "Resultado: " + imc + " | " + classificacao;

  alert("Sua classificação é: [" + classificacao + "]");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="peso" placeholder="Seu peso em kg"><br><br>
<input type="text" class="m" placeholder="Sua altura em metro(s)"><br><br>
<input type="text" class="cm" placeholder="Sua altura em centímetro(s)">

<button onclick="clicar()">Resultado</button>

<p class="resultado" style="color:blue; font-weight: bold;"></p>

<table>
  <thead>
    <th style="text-align:center;">IMC</th>
    <th style="text-align:center;">Classificação do IMC</th>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="tbody-imc">
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:center;">
        <16</td>
          <td style="text-align:center;">Magreza grave</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:center;">16 a
        <17</td>
          <td style="text-align:center;">Magreza Moderada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:center;">17 a
        <18.5</td>
          <td style="text-align:center;">Magreza Leve</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:center;">18.5 a
        <25</td>
          <td style="text-align:center;">Saudável</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:center;">25 a
        <30</td>
          <td style="text-align:center;">Sobrepeso</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:center;">30 a
        <35</td>
          <td style="text-align:center;">Obesidade Grau I</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:center;">35 a
        <40</td>
          <td class="text-center">Obesidade Grau II</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:center;">>40</td>
      <td style="text-align:center;">Obesidade Grau III</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```